# Computing covariance matrix given partial elements

Tags: probability, covariance

I have a random vector $\mathbf{X}$ consisting of three random variables, $\mathbf{X} = [X_1 X_2 X_3]^T$. I am given a partial covariance matrix C for $\mathbf{X}$, which is
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 0 & ? \\
? & ? & ? \\
0 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the $?$ entry implies we do not have a value. There are three parts I must compute. I have given my approaches below. Are they correct?

a) What are the values of the $?$ entries?

Since $\operatorname{cov}(X_a, X_b) = \operatorname{cov}(X_b, X_a)$, we know right away the off diagonal terms:
$$C=
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & ? & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I do not believe we can compute $\operatorname{cov}(X_2,X_2)=\operatorname{var}[X_2]$ since $$\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2) = E[X_1\cdot X_2] - E[X_1]E[X_2],\quad \operatorname{var}[X_2] = E[X_2^2]-E^2[X^2]$$
(inside outside rule).

I know that covariance matrices are positive semidefinite but I do not see how I can exploit that fact to determine the center term.

b) Are any of the random variables correlated?

Yes, $X_3$ and $X_2$ are correlated because $\operatorname{cov}(X_2,X_3)>0$, otherwise they would be orthogonal (and thus uncorrelated).

c) What is $\operatorname{var}[X_3]$?

$\operatorname{var}[X_3] = 4$ based on the definition of a covariance matrix and $C_{3,3}=4$.

Comment: thanks for the cleanup.  I am new here.

Comment: $C_{2,3}$ should be $1$ to match $C_{3,2}$. At the moment you've entered $0$.

Comment: @Alex you are right. that was a type.

Comment: The only constraint on $Var(X_2)$ that I can see is that $Var(X_2) \geq 1/4$. This is because $Cov(X_2, X_3)^2 \leq Var(X_2) Var(X_3)$ by Cauchy-Schwarz and so $1 \leq Var(X_2) \cdot 4$ so $1/4 \leq Var(X_2)$. I tried using the fact that $C$ must be positive semidefinite but it didn't yield any other bound. Cauchy-Schwarz: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory